# Cleaner data-bind within Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to using Knockout and am doing a very basic implementation that changes the color with a observable. Is there a cleaner way to write the following code?

```
<div class="selected" data-bind="style: { background: fullHexCode(mainScreenNavigationSelector()) !== false ? fullHexCode(mainScreenNavigationSelector()) : 'white' }"></div>
```

I have this in multiple spots on my page and they all use different params for the  `fullHexCode()` function. It looks extremely messy. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the logic depends on another observable so you could use a computed observable -- in the snippet below the **backgroundColor** computed observable depends on the **mainScreenNavigationSelector** observable.

That's just a simple example, you'll have to adjust it to your specific situation.

```js
var MyViewModel = function () {
  this.mainScreenNavigationSelector = ko.observable(false);

  this.backgroundColor = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.mainScreenNavigationSelector() ? 'green' : 'red'; 
  }, this);

  this.toggleColor = function() {
    this.mainScreenNavigationSelector(!this.mainScreenNavigationSelector());
  }
}

var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="selected" data-bind="style: { 'background-color': backgroundColor }">
  TEST
</div>

<button data-bind="click: toggleColor">Toggle Color</button>
```

Comment: Now how would I pass a parameter to that function?

Answer (score 0):

You may deduplicate your HTML code by defining methods in your viewmodel. Named computeds are even better as they are naturally *memoized*, that is evaluated only once if used repeatedly in your HTML.

You may also factorize heavy expressions as *with:* or *let:* bindings in the parent node. For example: `<div class='some-container' data-bind="let: { v: mainScreenNavigationSelector() }">... bindings based on v here... </div>`.

Notice: **let** is better than *with* for this purpose. But it's a new binding which will be available *in the next release* of KO.  You can polyfill it with a custom binding.

When JS expressions can't be avoided in your HTML code, try to make them as slick as possible. For example:

```
<div data-bind="style: {
     background: fullHexCode(mainScreenNavigationSelector()) || 'white'
}"></div>
```

In Javascript, logical operator doesn't return true or false but the actual value of the last evaluated arguments. So:

- a || b return a if not "falsy", otherwise b
- a && b return b if a not "falsy", otherwise a

The last idiom is useful in KO bindings because contrary to Angular, KO bindings are regular JS expressions. They fail if some null/undefined occurs in a dot sequence (like a.b if a is undefined).

So instead of some tertiary operator hell like `data-bind="text: object != null ? (object.a != undefined ? object.a : 'None') : 'None'"`, just write `data-bind="text: object && object.a || 'None'"`

Also [] and {} are not falsy, and it's actually a good thing. It allows to write things like `data-bind="foreach: foo.optionalArray || ['default', 'stuff']"`

However, `Number(0)` is false. So beware of something like `data-bind="with: object.id && 'saved' || 'new'"` which may not work as expected if 0 is a valid object id.

Also this last trick. If `data-bind="text: name"` fails because name is undefined , then `"data-bind="text: name || 'anonymous'"` will still fail, but `"data-bind='text: $data.name || 'anonymous'"` will work as expected. As a convention, I write `$data.attribute` instead of `attribute` to convey the info about dealing with a optional attribute.